# Right formula, wrong output

Tags: google-sheets

```
M11= 154,535 ; M18= 11,241 ; M22= =IF(M18>0,IF(M11>=120000, "SHARE","DON'T SHARE"))
```

M22 results in 'SHARE' which is the desired result.

```
O11= 157,600 ; O18= -16,586 ; O22= =IF(O18>0,IF(O11>=120000, "SHARE","DON'T SHARE"))
```

O22 results in 'FALSE' which is not the desired result.

What can be the issue (why doesn't it just show `DON'T SHARE`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because O18 is less than 0 (-16,586), and you dont have an alternative for the first IF, "IF(O18>0", and when it fails, the logical return is FALSE.

Your formula must be like:

```
=IF(O18>0,IF(O11>=120000, "SHARE","DON'T SHARE"), "DON'T SHARE")
```

or

```
=IF((AND(O18>0,O11>=120000), "SHARE","DON'T SHARE")
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: yeah this worked quite well. Thanks. I was confused because I used my formula in some other instances and it worked. I guess I will have to understand the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `IF` statements, but only an `Else` statement for the nested `IF`

You would need a second `Else`

`=IF(O18>0,IF(O11>=120000, "Share", "Don't Share"), "Don't Share")`

The IF format is

`IF (CONDITION, VALUE_IF_TRUE, VALUE_IF_FALSE)`

With formatting it's easier to spot. You are essentialy saying

```
IF (CONDITION, 
     IF (SECOND_CONDITION,
          SECOND_CONDITION_TRUE,
          SECOND_CONDITION_FALSE),
     VALUE_IF_FALSE (EMPTY IN YOUR EXAMPLE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a nested IF and already the first one returns "FALSE" !
Try it like this:

```
O11=-16,586; O18=157,600; O22= =IF(O18>0,IF(O11>=120000, "SHARE","DON'T SHARE"))
```

Comment: thats doesnt solve the problem, because when you change the O18 variable, for a number lower than 0, the result will be FALSE again.

Comment: @JuanC.V. Sorry but you haven't understand what I mean, please read my answer ! Remember, the question was "why doesnt it just show 'DON'T SHARE'?"

Comment: Yes, I've undestand, but you only changes the O18 value, and do not rectify the O22 formula. He wants  a formula that returns "DON'T SHARE" when O18 <= 0 or O11 < 120000. If you dont rectify the O22 formula, the output will be FALSE the next time that O18 value is less than 0